# filtering events from graph api facebook

Tags: php, facebook, events, facebook-graph-api

I need to get all events of an user, but from now.
I'm using facebook api sdk v3.0

this is my code:

```
if ($user) {
                try {
                    $events = $facebook->api("/me/events");
                } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
                    echo ($e);
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run a FQL query similar to something like:

```
SELECT eid, name, start_time, end_time 
FROM event 
WHERE eid IN (SELECT eid 
              FROM event_member 
              WHERE uid = me()) 
and start_time > now()
```

This will require the `user_events` [extended permission](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/).

**Full example:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<a href="#" onclick="getEvents();return false;">Get Events</a>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<script>
  FB.init({ appId  : 'yourAppId', status : true, cookie : true, xfbml  : true });

  function getEvents() {  
    FB.login(function(response) {
      if (response.session && response.perms) {
        FB.api(
          {
            method: 'fql.query',
            query: 'SELECT eid, name, start_time, end_time FROM event WHERE eid IN (SELECT eid FROM event_member WHERE uid = me()) and start_time > now()'
          },
          function(response) {
            alert('Events: ' + JSON.stringify(response));
          }
        );
      }
    } , {perms:'user_events'}); 
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks!!! 
I read this documentation http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/event/ and I try to use SELECT * but it don't permission.

Answer (score 1):

you'll have to loop through them and  unset unwanted

Comment: maybe FQL query but I'm not using it